# keyCode to character with libgdx keydown event

Tags: java, libgdx

I've got a custom textbox that I've written for my game and I'm trying to receive keyboard input. I thought this really can't be that hard, but I've spent a while searching now, and can't find an easy way to convert from the Keycode passed to a character. I'm assuming there must be an easy way to achieve this rather than me creating my own lookup. If someone could please point me in the right direction that'd be much appreciated.

I need this to work for both phone and desktop input.

Option 2 is to resort to the libgdx UI controls, but I *thought* spending 15 minutes knocking up my own textbox would be quicker than me learning all that... not quite as quick as I'd hoped.

Thanks

edit: The libgdx documention suggests that Input.Keys contains a static toString(int keycode) method... but it doesn't seem to be there. Has it been moved elsewhere?

Comment: What functionality do you need out of your textbox that the default libgdx textbox doesn't provide?

Comment: @MartinCarney nothing, but as this is the only generic UI control I needed I thought this route would be easier than learning a new section of libgdx... now it's just become my nemesis. :-)

Comment: Make sure you're using the latest version of libGDX (1.0), as that's when Input.Keys.toString(int keycode) was added.

Comment: @kabb I just copied over the latest nightly, still no sign of it. Thanks.

Comment: @kabb I just checked on github and it is there, so I've messed up somewhere. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `keyTyped` event instead.

From the [documentation of **`InputListener`**](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/InputListener.html),
in contrast to `keyUp` and `keyDown` events which provide a keycode, `keyTyped` event provides you with the character converted from the keycode which can be directly used in your case.

Good luck.

Comment: Do you know if the keyTyped event is a new addition? I'm surprised I didn't spot that originally. Thanks.

Comment: It's not a new addition. The only major changes I've noticed in recent times is `touchUp` returning `boolean`. `InputListener` has had only 4 commits after you posted this question.